# Proof with using combination proof (no algerbic methods) that $n^2=\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)$

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following problem :

Proof using combination :
$$n^2=\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)$$

I used the following problem :

Problem : Number of vectors of length $2$, with letters $\{1,2,..,n\}$

Left : choose the first letter $n$ possibilities then choose the second letter $n$ possibilities.

Right : I can't figure it out, what $(2i-1)$ has to do?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2i-1$ is the number of vectors of length $2$ with letters $1,\cdots ,n$ for which the maximum entry is exactly $i$

Comment: could you go into to go into detail? I can't see why this is true, if $i$ is the maximum entry, than we have ${1,2,..,i}$ then its should be $i*i$ (hence choose the first letter, and the second letter) why its $2i-1$?

Comment: @JaVaPG The vectors are $(1,i),(2,i),\cdots (i-1,i)$ , $(i,1),(i,2),\cdots (i,i-1)$ and finally $(i,i)$ making $2(i-1)+1=2i-2+1=2i-1$ vectors. With "maximum entry" I mean the maximum of the entries of the vector. Did you notice the crucial word "exactly" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can draw square $n\times n$ and inside this square another squares $(n-1)\times(n-1)$,... with the same vertex and use $n^2-(n-1)^2=2n-1.$

Comment: As shown here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_without_words